# Laravel 4.2 Soft Delete not working correctly

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, soft-delete

I just started to work on a project with a clean laravel 4.2 installation (from 5 days ago).
I have a model defined like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Code extends Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function group() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Group');
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

}
```

The table is created with `$table->softDeletes();`, and has a nullable deleted_at column.

Now when I delete a record with `Code::find(1)->delete();` the deleted_at column is filled with current date.

But then when I do `Code::all()`, or `Code::find(1)`, the result includes soft deleted records, but I expected it not to include them unless I specifically want deleted results...

I've already read http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/upgrade#upgrade-4.2 and my model reflects what is written there.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in 4.2?

Comment: It doesn't work for me either, I also followed the upgrade procedure, I gave up, waiting for 5.

Comment: It seems to be a bug or so, I also never get it to work properly in 4.2. My advice: change to 5.0 or sse the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501066/laravel-4-2-soft-delete-not-working

Comment: did you try updating your laravel/framework to a probable new version 4.2.*?

Comment: @Luceos I updated to 5.0 some time ago for that project. I never resolved the actual problem with 4.2 (but didn't update to newer 4.2 release at the time, so it could be resolved, but I can't check anymore).

Comment: Check this link, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45669204/1838205

Comment: @BKO, thank You for replying. This issue is outdated (look at previous comment), and as far as I see, your response in that link for 4.2 looks the same as the one in my question (uses same trait), so it's not an applicable answer to this issue.